# How to debug an external console configuration in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, pdcurses

I'm writing a C++ program in CLion using the PDCurses library. Because of this, I have to run the program in an external console. Command prompt in my case since I am on windows.

I managed to do this with the following configuration:
[image: CLion build configuration]

This configuration works, but it also seems to disable my debugger. Any breakpoints are skipped over completely.

The default configuration debugs and hit breakpoints just fine, but it doesn't run or display properly.

How do I fix this configuration so it works with the debugger, and still runs the application in my command prompt?